# Allow user to do anything within his own schema but not create or drop the schema itself

Tags: sql-server, schema, permissions

I have created a schema in SQL Azure and granted the following permissions to a database role:

```
CREATE ROLE myrole AUTHORIZATION dbo;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'myrole', 'myuser';

CREATE SCHEMA myschema AUTHORIZATION dbo;

GRANT ALTER, CONTROL, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE, VIEW 
DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::myschema TO myrole;

GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE VIEW TO myrole;
```

Through the above defined permissions `myuser` can create/drop his own schema, so to overcome the problem I tried the ALTER ANY SCHEMA permission. But this permission also denies the user to create/drop tables.

What permissions are required in order to allow the user to do anything within his own schema but not be able to create or drop the schema itself?

Answer (score 13):

There is no need to grant `CONTROL` on the schema.
The permission required to [`DROP SCHEMA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186751.aspx) is either `CONTROL` on the schema or `ALTER ANY SCHEMA` at the database level, and that is why your user was able to drop the schema. Removing these two permissions will prevent the role-associated users from creating and droping the schema (unless they have higher level permissions of course).

The required permission to `CREATE` `ALTER` and `DROP` other objects is the `CREATE` permission for the object type (table\procedure\function\view) combined with `ALTER` permission on the schema.
You already have these permissions in your script, so all that you have to do is remove the `CONTROL` permission. For reference, here is a [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx) list of `DDL` statements where You can find the required permission for all object types.

For the lazy, here is your code after removing the unnecessary permission:

```
CREATE ROLE myrole AUTHORIZATION dbo;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'myrole', 'myuser';

CREATE SCHEMA myschema AUTHORIZATION dbo;

GRANT ALTER, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT,
          UPDATE, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::myschema TO myrole;

GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE VIEW TO myrole;
```

Comment: But the user will be able to create objects under other schema too?

Answer (score 5):

Note that since the new schema has the authorization of "dbo", the user will be able to indirectly access all database objects where the schema is owned by dbo.

Example:

```
select * from dbo.test; --fails

create view myschema.test
as 
select * 
from dbo.test; --view is created

select * from myschema.test;  --contents of dbo.test now revealed.
```

This is correct operation of the SQL Server engine; permissions permeate into other schemas with the same authorization.  To restrict such access, here is an option for the schema creation:

```
CREATE SCHEMA myschema AUTHORIZATION myrole;
```

Comment: This is a very good point - the owner of the schema is crucial to the permissions the user has.